# EXC_BREAKPOINT code=1 in _CFRunLoopServiceMachPort

Tags: ios, debugging

I'm getting some odd behaviour. In my code, if I enable debugging, the debugger stops here:

[image]

Afterwards, even if I disable debugging and hit continue, the debugger remains stuck there.

If I don't enable the debugger, it doesn't seem to stop. What in the world is going on here? Here's the stack trace... it seems rather useless to me, but that might just be because I have no clue what's happening:

[image]

Comment: Clean your project, and try again.

Comment: If you disable breakpoints, is it OK? Do you have any symbolic breakpoints set up?

Comment: So far I've found that if I disable debugging it's ok. If I disable all individual breakpoints, but enable debugging, it's ok. There was a symbolic breakpoint, but disabling / removing it seems to make no difference. I'm working through the breakpoints one by one to find the culprit...

Comment: Ok... so it seems removing the symbolic breakpoint *then* cleaning and rebuilding gets rid of the issue. I'm still really not sure what I've just witnessed :D

Comment: I sometime have an `EXC_BREAKPOINT` without any apparent reason. I clean, restart XCode or switch targets randomly, and it does the trick. I can't help you further.

Comment: You don't need to... problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: what a waste of my valuable time... thanks for confirming what I feared!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable breakpoints, and especially any symbolic breakpoints set up, then clean your project, and try again.

I sometime have an `EXC_BREAKPOINT` without any apparent reason ; then I clean, restart Xcode, toggle debugging or switch targets randomly, and it somehow does the trick.

Comment: This situation now happens on my device and a clean/restart doesn't fix it. However your comment encouraged me to try in the simulator and there, I don't get the EXC_BREAKPOINT. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is also sometimes caused by running Instruments (for example Zombies or Leaks) at the same time. Some instruments work by setting breakpoints that will not show up in XCode, but will nevertheless break in the debugger.